# How to list permissions on a schema?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

In SSMS, if you follow the path [Database] > Security > Schemas and view any schema properties, you have a tab "permissions" that list all the permissions that every user have on that specific schema.

I would like to make a query that gives me the same output than that tab. I tried using sys.database_principals, database_permissions and sys_objects but I can't retrieve the permissions linked to schemas.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using the accepted answer from [List schema permissions](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/fe9d6dba-3bff-4250-aa26-45c90c96f476/list-schema-permissions?forum=sqlsecurity), this would probably give you what you want.

```
--demo setup
CREATE DATABASE listschema
GO

USE listschema
GO

CREATE SCHEMA TestSchema
GO

CREATE USER TestUser WITHOUT LOGIN
GO

GRANT SELECT
    ON SCHEMA::TestSchema
    TO TestUser

DENY INSERT
    ON SCHEMA::TestSchema
    TO TestUser
GO

--The actual query
SELECT state_desc
    ,permission_name
    ,'ON'
    ,class_desc
    ,SCHEMA_NAME(major_id)
    ,'TO'
    ,USER_NAME(grantee_principal_id)
FROM sys.database_permissions AS PERM
JOIN sys.database_principals AS Prin
    ON PERM.major_ID = Prin.principal_id
        AND class_desc = 'SCHEMA'
WHERE major_id = SCHEMA_ID('TestSchema')
    AND grantee_principal_id = user_id('TestUser')
    --AND    permission_name = 'SELECT'
GO

--cleanup
USE tempdb
GO

DROP DATABASE listschema
```

---

```
| state_desc | permission_name | (No column name) | class_desc | (No column name) | (No column name) | (No column name) |
|------------|-----------------|------------------|------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
| DENY       | INSERT          | ON               | SCHEMA     | TestSchema       | TO               | TestUser         |
| GRANT      | SELECT          | ON               | SCHEMA     | TestSchema       | TO               | TestUser         |
```

Comment: Thanks. I already tried that query but the output was empty. I tried it again after creating TestSchema and TestUser and now it returns me the same output as you. I don't understand why my permissions on other schemas won't show...

Comment: @Kimo - you'll probably need to update your question and include a minimal and verifiable example of the problem - we need information (tsql scripts) similar to my example.  Since we can't see what's on your server, we're just guessing.

Comment: I updated my question

Answer (score 1):

Also, if you would need the exact queries as SSMS Launches them, they are not that readable, and several are used to get the result shown in SSMS.

**The base query when opening the permissions on my test schema:**

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT
grantee_principal.name AS [Grantee],
CASE grantee_principal.type WHEN ''R'' THEN 3 WHEN ''A'' THEN 4 ELSE 2 END - CASE ''database'' WHEN  ''database'' THEN 0 ELSE 2 END AS [GranteeType]
FROM
sys.schemas AS s
INNER JOIN sys.database_permissions AS prmssn ON prmssn.major_id=s.schema_id AND prmssn.minor_id=0 AND prmssn.class=3
INNER JOIN sys.database_principals AS grantee_principal ON grantee_principal.principal_id = prmssn.grantee_principal_id
WHERE
(s.name=@_msparam_0)',N'@_msparam_0 nvarchar(4000)',@_msparam_0=N'TEST'
```

**Resulting in a row for each permission granted**

```
Grantee GranteeType
guest   2
bla 2
bla 2
```

*(Queries used to grant)*

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON SCHEMA :: test TO bla;
GRANT INSERT ON SCHEMA :: test TO bla;
GRANT INSERT ON SCHEMA :: test TO guest;
```

**The second query, for each principal, bla in my example**

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT
ascii(prmssn.state) AS [PermissionState],
null AS [Code],
grantor_principal.name AS [Grantor],
prmssn.type AS [SqlCodePP],
CASE WHEN (prmssn.class=4 or prmssn.class=101 ) THEN CASE (SELECT oc.type FROM sys.database_principals AS oc WHERE oc.principal_id = prmssn.major_id) WHEN ''R'' THEN CASE prmssn.class WHEN 4 THEN 201 ELSE 301 END WHEN ''A'' THEN 202 ELSE CASE prmssn.class WHEN 4 THEN 200 ELSE 101 END END ELSE prmssn.class END AS [HiddenObjectClass]
FROM
sys.schemas AS s
INNER JOIN sys.database_permissions AS prmssn ON prmssn.major_id=s.schema_id AND prmssn.minor_id=0 AND prmssn.class=3
INNER JOIN sys.database_principals AS grantor_principal ON grantor_principal.principal_id = prmssn.grantor_principal_id
INNER JOIN sys.database_principals AS grantee_principal ON grantee_principal.principal_id = prmssn.grantee_principal_id
WHERE
(grantee_principal.name=@_msparam_0)and((s.name=@_msparam_1))',N'@_msparam_0 nvarchar(4000),@_msparam_1 nvarchar(4000)',@_msparam_0=N'bla',@_msparam_1=N'TEST'
```

**Not really readable result**

```
PermissionState Code    Grantor SqlCodePP   HiddenObjectClass
71              NULL     dbo       EX           3
71              NULL     dbo       IN           3
```

**Combining the two queries, you could get something a bit more readable**

```
DECLARE @SCHEMA varchar(255) = 'test'
SELECT DISTINCT
CASE WHEN prmssn.state = 'D' then 'Deny'  WHEN prmssn.state = 'R' THEN 'REVOKE' WHEN prmssn.state = 'G' THEN 'Grant'   ELSE  ' Grant With Grant Option' end as permissionstate,
grantor_principal.name AS [Grantor],
prmssn.permission_name AS [name],
class_desc,Grantees.grantee
FROM
sys.schemas AS s
INNER JOIN sys.database_permissions AS prmssn ON prmssn.major_id=s.schema_id AND prmssn.minor_id=0 AND prmssn.class=3
INNER JOIN sys.database_principals AS grantor_principal ON grantor_principal.principal_id = prmssn.grantor_principal_id
INNER JOIN sys.database_principals AS grantee_principal ON grantee_principal.principal_id = prmssn.grantee_principal_id
INNER JOIN (SELECT
grantee_principal.name AS [Grantee]
FROM
sys.schemas AS s
INNER JOIN sys.database_permissions AS prmssn ON prmssn.major_id=s.schema_id AND prmssn.minor_id=0 AND prmssn.class=3
INNER JOIN sys.database_principals AS grantee_principal ON grantee_principal.principal_id = prmssn.grantee_principal_id
WHERE
(s.name= @SCHEMA)) as Grantees
on Grantees.grantee = grantee_principal.name
WHERE
((s.name=@SCHEMA))
```

**Resulting in:**

```
permissionstate Grantor name    class_desc  grantee
Grant            dbo    EXECUTE SCHEMA      bla
Grant            dbo    INSERT  SCHEMA      bla
Grant            dbo    INSERT  SCHEMA      guest
```

Answer (score 1):

With the following command I managed to get a more correct response :

```
SELECT state_desc
    ,permission_name
    ,'ON'
    ,class_desc
    ,SCHEMA_NAME(major_id)
    ,'TO'
    ,USER_NAME(grantee_principal_id)
FROM sys.database_permissions AS PERM
JOIN sys.database_principals AS Prin
    ON PERM.grantee_principal_id = Prin.principal_id
        AND PERM.class_desc = 'SCHEMA'
```

The thing is that Scott's answer I think the link between `sys.database_permissions` and `sys.database_principals` is incorrect. Why joining over `major_id` since that represents the schema and not the grantee (principal).

But thanks Scott !! your answer helps a lot !